# Remove the parent node in javascript starting from a string

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a string. The string is a callback from an adserver, and this is the format

```
<div style="background-color: yellow">
<div>
<div style="left: 10px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 80%;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DkrwfY2jw4" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove the parent div only if he style has yellow as background color. Of course I cannot use jquery.

I try to transform the string in an HTML fragment using

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = a.response.html;
var elements = div.childNodes;
```

but I cannot find a way to check for the presence of the attribute and, if true, remove the parent node keeping the childs.

Comment: is it just about changing the background color?

Comment: You should be able to get the background-color by using something like:
`someDiv = document.getElementById("id_of_concerned_div"); // or div.innerHTML as per your code
someDiv.getAttribute('style'); // this should return background-color: yellow`

Comment: and to remove that yellow colored div, try something like `div.innerHTML = a.response.html.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

The `div` itself shouldn't be a problem, so you can just set the background to transparent if its original background color is yellow:

```
var s = `<div style="background-color: yellow">
<div>
<div style="left: 10px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 80%;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DkrwfY2jw4" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>` 
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s; // replace with response...
if (div.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor == 'yellow') div.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dLr1tco/)

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over the childNodes and check if the div has a specific style.

```js
function checkandAppend(nodes) {

  
  for(node in nodes){
     if (nodes.hasOwnProperty(node))
     if(nodes[node].getAttribute("style") == 'background-color: yellow')
     {
 
        if(nodes[node].childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) // some browser interpret line break as first child 
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(nodes[node].childNodes[1]);
        else
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(nodes[node].childNodes[0]);
     }
     else
     {
       document.querySelector("body").appendChild(nodes[node]);
     }
  }
 
}


var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div style="background-color: yellow"> <div> <div style="left: 10px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 80%;"> <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DkrwfY2jw4" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe> </div> </div> </div>'

checkandAppend(div.childNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the style is set inline, you can simply read the style property of the div. Create a div, insert the HTML, then check the first div. I guess that you want to insert this in the document, so if the first div has been set to yellow, insert its first div child node (i.e. the second in the tree) in the document. Otherwise, insert the first div.

This method is not robust, but without further information on how to select the div, or what to do with it once selected, there's not much more you can do.

I've replaced the iFrame with some text, I don't think it's relevant to the answer.

```js
var response = '<div style="background-color: yellow"><div><div style="left: 10px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 80%;">iframe</div></div></div>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = response;
var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('div');

if (divs[0].style.backgroundColor == 'yellow') {
  document.body.appendChild(divs[1]);
} else {
  document.body.appendChild(divs[0]);
}
```

You could replace the *if..else* with:

```
document.body.appendChild(divs[+(divs[0].style.backgroundColor == 'yellow')]);
```

but that might be a bit obfuscated.

Comment: thank you so much, the problem is that sometimes background-color is not defined. 

So I have to check also if is defined.